# How to space or control the line numbers in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-formatting

I am doing some data entry and each entry has about 5 or 6 lines. I would like each data entry to be labeled per the line numbers in notepad. Here is an example image.

[image]

In this image I would like **`Name: Test 1`** to start at line `18`  and **`Name: Test 2`** to start at line `19`. There must be just space as if it's typed in a single line. One `Test` entry must be on a single label number in the left side. How can I achieve this?

As always thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You must edit file, so line "Test1" will be one line, and "Test2" will be next line. Delete all line-end chars between Test1 and 2.